# React:The Api i am using dosen't give me an id number to use as a unique key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So it is advisable to give your lists a unique key when re-rendering them.Most endpoints return objects with an id number to help with that.But which trick do i use if an object dosent have the id property?
Do i get the index of each list in the array to use as the key?
Please show with demonstration.
Thank you

Comment: Yes index with some prefix or suffix would makes sense, unless you use the same component twice on the page. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: React keys need only be unique within siblings, so using a component twice is perfectly fine. If the data has a unique field per entry (i.e. names, etc...), that will work. Or you can create a unique id, though I wouldn't recommend incorporating the index because any change in the length of the array could potentially rerender the entire array. I'd suggest preprocessing your data and adding a unique identifier, uuidV4 is good for this. If you provide an example of your response data I don't mind creating a demo for adding unique id property.

Comment: 611: {rate: 0.389165, high: 0.389165, low: 0.389165, vol: null, cap: null, …}
ABC: {rate: 59.99, high: 59.99, low: 59.99, vol: null, cap: null, …}
ACP: {rate: 0.014931, high: 0.014931, low: 0.014931, vol: null, cap: null, …}

Comment: That looks more like an object? How are you trying to render that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use indexes for keys that can negatively impact performance. If you don't have an id you can combine properties (name, description) or you can make use of existing npm packages like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid), etc

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

I leave you an example here:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={uuidv4()}>
   {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: For more info on "indices are a bad idea" [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: FYI, the keys don't affect performance, only how react decides what needs to be **re**rendered. If mapping static values then index is perfectly safe. Also, you don't want to generate the unique ID's on-the-fly as anything that causes the component to rerender will then generate all new ID's again.

Answer (score 0):

If your response data is an object

```
{
  611: { rate: 0.389165, high: 0.389165, low: 0.389165, vol: null, cap: null, ... },
  ABC: { rate: 59.99, high: 59.99, low: 59.99, vol: null, cap: null, ... },
  ACP: { rate: 0.014931, high: 0.014931, low: 0.014931, vol: null, cap: null, ... },
  ...
}
```

Then I would suggest using the object's keys as react keys. They should be unique within the object literal so they would meet the requirements of react's [lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) documentation.

[Keys need only be unique among siblings](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings)

To extract the object keys for use as react keys then [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is your friend.

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable string-keyed property `[key, value]` pairs.

```
[
  [611, { rate: 0.389165, high: 0.389165, low: 0.389165, vol: null, cap: null, ... }],
  [ABC, { rate: 59.99, high: 59.99, low: 59.99, vol: null, cap: null, ... }],
  [ACP, { rate: 0.014931, high: 0.014931, low: 0.014931, vol: null, cap: null, ... }],
  ...
]
```

So if the above object represents response data it can be referenced as

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key, item]) => {
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      { /* render array element variable named item */ }
    </div>
  );
})
```